# How did Dr. Stu Price lose his tooth in The Hangover?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hangover

In the morning after the big blackout in [The Hangover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hangover), Dr. Stu Price realized that he was missing a tooth.

How did Dr. Stu lose his tooth?  Did they talk about the lost tooth in a later part of  the movie? Is it shown in the movie how he lost his tooth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the snapshots I took for you to let you see the tooth plucking scene.

**Dr. Stu plucking his tooth**

[image]

**Dr. Stu plucked his tooth**

[image]

These scenes are shown in the credits when they were watching the video camera of what they had recorded of that night which was discovered later. The tooth plucking happened when they were in the bar where they met Jade. After the incident Jade and Stu got married to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean how he lost it? During the night someone said he was a bad dentist and bet with him that he couldn't extract a tooth on himself, which he then tried to defend his honor as dentist, and well, he could.

I think this is told by somebody during the adventures of recollecting their memories (maybe the doctor at the hospital or *Stu*'s *"wife"*). Or maybe it was even shown as part of his wedding video.

Comment: I don't remember exactly at which scene they discussed about missing tooth story.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk It was around when they met the stripper in her house, IIRC

Comment: @SomnathMuluk So you remember *how* he lost it but just not *how or when they explained that* (which would make my answer somehow irrelevant)? As a general rule, please keep your questions as clear and detailed as possible (this also in light of the current discussion under the question). You don't need to be a pro in English language to write a good and understandable question.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I mean 'I saw he lost tooth and bleeding. But how did he lost tooth? When did they discussed about lost tooth?'